# Solve Equations from Equations Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving

Well, I need a way to solve equations by another var got from other equation in Mathematica 8. Example:

```
a + b = 2c
c + 2 = d
d = 2b
```

It will chose the best equation for the given values and solve the rest.
With some given values, like `a = 1` and `c = 3`, it solves the system, getting the values for the respective variable.
*Will use this for physics' formulas.

Comment: It's a good idea to show what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Solve or Reduce functions. The syntax is

> Solve[{LIST OF EQUATIONS}, {Variables to solve for}]

So in this case:

```
Solve[{a + b == 2 c, c + 2 == d, d == 2 b}, {a, b, c, d}]
(*->
{{a -> -4 + (3 d)/2, b -> d/2, c -> -2 + d}}
*)
```

There are 4 variables and only 3 equations, so there are infinite solutions.
They lie on the 4-d line `(-4 + (3 n)/2, n/2, n-2, n)`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I put the Equation List in a Module or Block, it can´t solve the system.

Comment: @Odinfall could you explain what you mean by that? I'm not sure if I follow.

Comment: Running Solve or Reduce inside a module should work. For example: `solver[eqList_, varList_] := Module[{}, Reduce[eqList, varList]];`
`solver[{a + b == 2 c, c + 2 == d, d == 2 b}, {a, b, c, d}]` This exact code, although it works, is pointless because it is simply wrapping Reduce. However, if you need the results of reduce in a module (as it sounds like), you could use this set-up and add more things to the module. (In particular, you'd likely want to capture the output of the Reduce call in new variables.)